# controller exists , but the page is not found

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem with controller

I'm using a server on windows and everything it works fine , but on internet i'm trying to access the page social_apartament/beauty_life/ and the page is not found with code error 404
here is some info abou error

```
            [code] => 404
            [type] => CHttpException
            [errorCode] => 0
            [message] => Unable to resolve the request "beauty_life".
            [file] => /home1/moldovaj/public_html/testit/YiiRoot/framework/web/CWebApplication.php
            [line] => 287
            [trace] => #0 /home1/moldovaj/public_html/testit/YiiRoot/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(142): CWebApplication->runController('beauty_life')
#1 /home1/moldovaj/public_html/testit/YiiRoot/framework/base/CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#2 /home1/moldovaj/public_html/testit/www.social_apartament/index.php(13): CApplication->run()
#3 {main}
```

Structure on server is like this :

controllers/Beauty_LifeController.php
views/beauty_life/index.php

controler Beauty_LifeController is like this :

```
    <?php

class Beauty_LifeController extends Controller
{


    public function actionIndex()
    {


....

        $this->render('index',
            array(
                'models'=>$models,
                'pages' => $pages,
                'archive' => $archive,
                'monthNames'=>$monthNames
            )
        );

    }

}
```

is intersting when i type social_apartament/Beauty_Life/ with Lovercase letters i give an error : `CException - Beauty_LifeController cannot find the requested view "index".` , strange what can be the problem
host server is http://hostmonster.com , if it helps with something , 
Thank you for your help !!!

Comment: does the view file exist in the path protected\view\controller_name\index.php ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

windows is NOT case sensitive but linux does . Make **L**  lowercase in `Beauty_Life`.

You have to change class name as well as filename.

Answer (score 2):

Controller = BeautyLife and you try to get beautylife, you have to request with capital B and L to get the right controller.

See this link:"http://hugoware.net/blog/ignoring-case-with-mono-mvc"

Answer (score 1):

Better if you use controller naming convention.
Name your controller BeautyLifeController instead of Beauty_Life.

And also if you are using windows you would not have any problem regarding file naming but may have with linux.